# How can I enable HMR with Vue CLI and Yarn Workspaces?

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vue-cli, yarn-workspaces

I have a project with two packages:
components/
apps/

Both are built using @vue/cli, and I'm using yarn workspaces to manage dependencies.

Everything is working, except Hot Module Replacement when running the app.

- components/package.json: main: dist/components.umd.js
- app/package.json: components are a dependency, I import like import MyComponent from 'components'

In dev mode I run two tasks in parallel:

- components: vue-cli-service build --target lib --watch
- app: vue-cli-service serve

I want to change MyComponent in components/src/ and have it hot reload in the dev server.

However, I can only see the changes when I refresh the page.

I know the Vue cli splits source and vendor js bundles, so I thought this may be the cause of the problem?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any solution?